# Controlling a DC motor directly with Raspberry Pi GPIO without any external IC or Transistor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

I need to control a DC motor without the use of an external IC or transistor with the raspberry pi GPIO. I do not need direction or speed control. All I need is the motor to controlled by raspberry pi gpio.

Comment: What are the specs of your motor?

Comment: That's a terrible idea, and the only motor I would say is safe enough for this is a little vibration motor

Answer (score 6):

I would venture to say that you cannot drive a motor directly from a Raspberry Pi. According to the datasheet:

> GPIO ... source and sink current is configurable from 2 mA up to 16 mA.

16mA will probably be nowhere near enough to drive a motor, as even small ones tend to draw hundreds of milliamps. You will likely burn out the chips on the Pi. You really MUST use an external transistor, and probably an external power supply too.

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use an external transistor?

Comment: I have to present a project tomorrow in school and I cannot buy new parts now.

Comment: Should have started your project sooner rather than waiting until the last minute =P Does your school have an electronics lab? Perhaps you could borrow a transistor?

Comment: @derstrom8 is right. Forget about it. Find an appropriate transistor (salvage from just about any piece of electronics) or ask for an extension. Blowing up your Rpi helps nobody.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a bare DC motor, use a continuous rotation RC servo such the  Futaba S148. You can then control it with a series of logic-level pulses at approximately 20~50Hz. 1.5ms is stopped, 1ms is rotation in one direction 2ms on the other direction.

There are much nicer motors with built in controllers such as those from MicroMo, but they are spec'd (and priced) for professional applications.